# Python sqlite3 no such column very weird error

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to insert values to columns in a table of a sqlite3 DB 
as follows:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keys(name TEXT, po TEXT, options TEXT, identifier TEXT, currtime TEXT)""")
c.execute('INSERT INTO keys VALUES ( ' + Customer_Name + ' , ' + Purchase_Order + ' , ' + options + ' , ' + UUID + ' , ' + currtime + ' )')
```

These arguments are actually passed from HTML front end. I convert them from unicode to string as follows:

```
options = str(request.form.get("Software_Options"))
UUID = str(request.form.get("UUID_Identifier"))
Customer_Name = str(request.form.get("Customer_Name"))
Purchase_Order = str(request.form.get("Purchase_Order"))
currtime= str(datetime.datetime.now())[:10]
```

If the are integers there is no error.
If the input is a string ( e.g. joseph) it gives the following error. Any idea why?

```
OperationalError: no such column: joseph
```

Comment: Have you tried the other SQL insert syntax, where you specify the column names explictily? `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN)  
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);`

Comment: Yes I tried, 
c.execute('INSERT INTO keys (CustomerName, PurshaceOrder, GeneratedKey , CurrentTime) VALUES ( ' + Customer_Name + ' , ' + Purchase_Order + ' , ' + Generated_Key + ' , ' + currtime + ' )')

Still gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be obtaining the contents for one database record at a time from the web front-end. That being the case, you can build a record as a list and insert it in the database in the following way.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3 . connect ( 'db.sqlite' )
c = conn . cursor ( )

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keys(name TEXT, po TEXT, options TEXT, identifier TEXT, currtime TEXT)""")

oneRecord = [ 'joe', 'DA123', 'nilbymouth', '0034', '1653', ]
c.execute('INSERT INTO keys VALUES (?,?,?,?,? )', oneRecord)

conn.close()
```

The use of this type of construction, involving the '?' character, is also considered safer that others against injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But I'm curious to know why my method didn't know

Comment: And I wish I could tell you. (But I can't.) Anyway, you're welcome.